# Stream failed error on Cassandra 2.1.10

Tags: cassandra

I'm trying to get two nodes join an existing cassandra cluster of 4 nodes already. I'm facing an error of Stream failed when bootstrapping the node. For one of the node I tried setting auto_bootstrap to false, in which case it joined the cluster and I then did a nodetool repair. I'm really clueless as to what's causing the Stream failed error. I even tried setting 'streaming_socket_timeout_in_ms' to 1hour on the node being bootstrapped but it didnt help. nodetool scrub also tried on the source node

Excerpts of the error:

```
INFO  [StreamReceiveTask:2] 2016-08-30 09:23:26,316 StreamResultFuture.java:180 - [Stream #56d33930-6e93-11e6-a7ae-c71303d146a8] Session with <source_ip>/<source_ip> is complete
WARN  [StreamReceiveTask:2] 2016-08-30 09:23:26,318 StreamResultFuture.java:207 - [Stream #56d33930-6e93-11e6-a7ae-c71303d146a8] Stream failed
ERROR [main] 2016-08-30 09:23:26,322 CassandraDaemon.java:579 - Exception encountered during startup
java.lang.RuntimeException: Error during boostrap: Stream failed
    at org.apache.cassandra.dht.BootStrapper.bootstrap(BootStrapper.java:86) ~[apache-cassandra-2.1.10.jar:2.1.10]
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageService.bootstrap(StorageService.java:1148) ~[apache-cassandra-2.1.10.jar:2.1.10]
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageService.joinTokenRing(StorageService.java:938) ~[apache-cassandra-2.1.10.jar:2.1.10]
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageService.initServer(StorageService.java:734) ~[apache-cassandra-2.1.10.jar:2.1.10]
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageService.initServer(StorageService.java:611) ~[apache-cassandra-2.1.10.jar:2.1.10]
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.setup(CassandraDaemon.java:387) [apache-cassandra-2.1.10.jar:2.1.10]
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.activate(CassandraDaemon.java:562) [apache-cassandra-2.1.10.jar:2.1.10]
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.main(CassandraDaemon.java:651) [apache-cassandra-2.1.10.jar:2.1.10]
Caused by: org.apache.cassandra.streaming.StreamException: Stream failed
    at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.management.StreamEventJMXNotifier.onFailure(StreamEventJMXNotifier.java:85) ~[apache-cassandra-2.1.10.jar:2.1.10]
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures$4.run(Futures.java:1172) ~[guava-16.0.jar:na]
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors$SameThreadExecutorService.execute(MoreExecutors.java:297) ~[guava-16.0.jar:na]
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.ExecutionList.executeListener(ExecutionList.java:156) ~[guava-16.0.jar:na]
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.ExecutionList.execute(ExecutionList.java:145) ~[guava-16.0.jar:na]
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.setException(AbstractFuture.java:202) ~[guava-16.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.StreamResultFuture.maybeComplete(StreamResultFuture.java:208) ~[apache-cassandra-2.1.10.jar:2.1.10]
    at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.StreamResultFuture.handleSessionComplete(StreamResultFuture.java:184) ~[apache-cassandra-2.1.10.jar:2.1.10]
    at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.StreamSession.closeSession(StreamSession.java:415) ~[apache-cassandra-2.1.10.jar:2.1.10]
    at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.StreamSession.maybeCompleted(StreamSession.java:688) ~[apache-cassandra-2.1.10.jar:2.1.10]
    at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.StreamSession.taskCompleted(StreamSession.java:651) ~[apache-cassandra-2.1.10.jar:2.1.10]
    at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.StreamReceiveTask$OnCompletionRunnable.run(StreamReceiveTask.java:139) ~[apache-cassandra-2.1.10.jar:2.1.10]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471) ~[na:1.7.0_75]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262) ~[na:1.7.0_75]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) ~[na:1.7.0_75]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) ~[na:1.7.0_75]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) ~[na:1.7.0_75]
WARN  [StorageServiceShutdownHook] 2016-08-30 09:23:26,324 Gossiper.java:1450 - No local state or state is in silent shutdown, not announcing shutdown
INFO  [StorageServiceShutdownHook] 2016-08-30 09:23:26,324 MessagingService.java:735 - Waiting for messaging service to quiesce
INFO  [ACCEPT-/10.227.200.41] 2016-08-30 09:23:26,324 MessagingService.java:1011 - MessagingService has terminated the accept() thread
```

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation on adding nodes to a cluster (http://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.1/cassandra/operations/ops_add_node_to_cluster_t.html), you should NOT set auto_bootstrap to false

> Set the following properties in the cassandra.yaml and, depending on the snitch, the cassandra-topology.properties or cassandra-rackdc.properties configuration files:
>
> **auto_bootstrap** - This property is not listed in the default cassandra.yaml configuration file, but it might have been added and set to false by other operations. If it is not defined in cassandra.yaml, Cassandra uses true as a default value. For this operation, search for this property in the cassandra.yaml file. **If it is present, set it to true or delete it..**

That being said, I'm on 2.1.11 and I'm having the same problem as you.